# forms error and styling Problem in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

Hi I'm relatively new to Angular and I have one major problem and one small styling problem first let's go to the Major problem:
These are my passwords input I have the code from online and altered it a little bit.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Passwort</mat-label>
      <input matInput [type]="hidepwd ? 'password' : 'text'" id="passwordInput" [formControl]="password" required>
      <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hidepwd = !hidepwd" [attr.aria-label]="'Passwort anzeigen/verstecken'"
        [attr.aria-pressed]="hidepwd">
        <mat-icon>{{hidepwd ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-error *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
        {{getPasswordErrorMessage()}}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Passwort bestätigen</mat-label>
      <input matInput [type]="hidepwdrepeat ? 'password' : 'text'" id="confirmPasswordInput" [formControl]="confirmPassword" (input)="checkPasswordMatch()" required>
      <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hidepwdrepeat = !hidepwdrepeat" [attr.aria-label]="'Passwort anzeigen/verstecken'"
        [attr.aria-pressed]="hidepwdrepeat">
        <mat-icon>{{hidepwdrepeat ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-error *ngIf="confirmPassword.invalid && (confirmPassword.dirty || confirmPassword.touched)">
        {{getConfirmPasswordErrorMessage()}}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is the getConfirmPasswordErrorMessage function where I do the Error handling for the password confirmation in this function:

```
getConfirmPasswordErrorMessage() {
    if (this.confirmPassword.hasError('required')) {
      console.log("required");
      return 'Pflichtfeld';
    } 
    else if (this.password.value !== this.confirmPassword.value) {
      console.log("passwords dont match");
      return 'Passwörter stimmen nicht überein';
    } 
    else {
      console.log("no error");
      return '';
    }
  }
```

So now my question I get the error "Pflichtfeld" it's German for Mandatory field but i don't get the error that my passwords don't match why??

---

my styling question: this is my submit button:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="register()">Registrieren</button>
```

Why does it still look like this?:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDuu8.png)

I have tried with (input)="checkPasswordMatch()" like you see but still nothing

Comment: Impossible to say without a [mre], but my guess would be that you don't have a validator set up for your `confirmPassword` field, so `confirmPassword.invalid` evaluates to false. For the styling issue, did you include the button module and button theming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have not defined your Validators for the confirmPassword FormControl. mat-error is rendered only when the its corresponding form-control has an error. If you still want to see the error, just replace mat-error with a div or a span & remove the confirmPassword.invalid condition from ngIf.

Regarding the styling issue, please check if you have imported the - MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button' in your module.